# ParallelizationFactor in kinesis event source mapping

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli, amazon-kinesis

I'm looking to connect a Kinesis stream to a Lambda function via event source mapping, want to set the `parallelization-factor` value to any value between 1- 10 as suggested in the documention:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/create-event-source-mapping.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-eventsourcemapping.html#cfn-lambda-eventsourcemapping-startingposition

and an example at https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/new-aws-lambda-scaling-controls-for-kinesis-and-dynamodb-event-sources/

The following command results in an error:

```
aws lambda create-event-source-mapping --function-name myLambdaFunction \
--parallelization-factor 2 --batch-size 100 --starting-position LATEST \
--event-source-arn arn:aws:kinesis:eu-west-1:id:stream/mystreamname

Unknown options: --parallelization-factor, 2
```

If I look at the AWS CLI aws lambda create-event-source-mapping help, there is no option for `--parallelization-factor`

```
SYNOPSIS
            create-event-source-mapping
          --event-source-arn <value>
          --function-name <value>
          [--enabled | --no-enabled]
          [--batch-size <value>]
          [--starting-position <value>]
          [--starting-position-timestamp <value>]
          [--cli-input-json <value>]
          [--generate-cli-skeleton <value>]
```

There is a difference in documentation and the aws cli help. Is the parallelization factor not enabled for kinesis? What am I doing wrong?

PS: I have tried in `eu-west-1` and `us-east-1` regions.
I am getting the same error if I try to set `--maximum-batching-window-in-seconds`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the version of AWS CLI your using, because i can find the --parallelization-factor option when i tried the below command

`aws lambda create-event-source-mapping help`

[image]

This is version i'm using

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Abhinaya it worked. I upgraded my CLI and it works.